# How import a csv file as a dataframe?

Tags: r, csv

I want to import a csv file in R as a dataframe with name routes and in addition to name the columns of the dataframe..Any help??
I write routes<-read.csv("routes.csv") but i don't know how to name the columns!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will need to add header = TRUE, if the CSV file already has headers

```
   routes<-read.csv("routes.csv", header=TRUE)
```

if your file does not have headers you need to create column names eg: column names A, B, C

```
   colnames(routes) =c("A","B","C")
```

Comment: @Fotis instead of thanking the poster in the comments, you can show your gratitude by clicking the green check box next to the question to show that it solved your problem.